# Javascript google api call - How to add "url missing" to json obj if no picture url in response

Tags: javascript, json, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the url value of a user account on google drive.

I have successfully achieved this however, I believe that if there is no picture set then the response from my api call is that it will send me the object without the URL inside.

Here is the response.

```
"lastModifyingUser": {
"kind": "drive#user",
"displayName": string,
"picture": {
  "url": string
},
```

output:

Without display pic?

```
drive#user 
#Hidden Name
true 
#Hidden ID
```

With display pic?

```
drive#user 
#Hidden Name
#HIDDEN URL <-- Missing
false 
#Hidden ID
```

Anyways, I was wondering if I was able to determine the size of json objects in javascript and IF the url is missing, I would still like "URL Missing" in my imageDateObj.

Here is my code

```
    var id = resp.id;
    var obj = resp.lastModifyingUser;

                for(var k in obj) {
                    var value = obj[k];
                    if (typeof value === 'object') {
                        for (var k2 in value) {
                            var value2 = value[k2];
                            console.log(value2); //value 2 is the url
                            imageDateObj[id] = value2;
                        }
                    } else if(typeof value === 'undefined'){
                        console.log("url missing"); //not working
                    } 
                    else {
                        console.log(value);
                    }
                }
```

In other words, if Url is mising, add to

```
imageDateObj[id] = "url missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sorted it.

I added this

```
var count = Object.keys(obj).length
                    console.log(count);
                    if(count == 4){
                        imageDateObj[id] = "Url missing";
                    }
```